# Use an each block to print the names of all the Zombie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, for-loop, zombie-process

I'm trying to do the 'rails for zombies' course on codeschool, but I'm stuck on this one:

http://railsforzombies.org/levels/3/challenges/3

The frustrating thing about this course, is that you can't refine your answers, because you don't see the return value from incorrect solutions.

Anyway, the database looks like this:

```
id  name    graveyard
1   Ash     Glen Haven Memorial Cemetary
2   Bob     Chapel Hill Cemetary
3   Jim     My Fathers Basement
```

The challenge is to "Use an each block to print the names of all the Zombies"

My solution is:
    <% 
     zombies.each do |z| 
         puts z.name 
     end
    %>

This fails, but I don't get to see how it fails, so I can't refine it.
What is the solution?

Comment: Ps. Welcome to SO. Please read the FAQ. Also note that at SO, when someone answers your question and that answer helps you, you are supposed to accept that answer (and upvote it too).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% zombies.each do |z| %>
  #note the equal-to sign below. this means that the text will be sent as output
  <%= z.name %>
<% end %>
```

Notes:

- `puts` is used to output the text to the console
- `<%= %>` is the way to output text in an ERB template